# Python - Is it better to pass an SQLAlchemy model, or an id no. to query again?

Tags: python, performance, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Example code:

```
def primary_function(object_id):
    some_object = SomeObject.query.get(object_id)
    # Do stuff here
    secondary_function(unknown_parameter)


def secondary_function(unknown_parameter):
    # Do more stuff here
```

Both functions need access to `some_object`. Is it more efficient to have `unknown_parameter` be the object itself, or would it be better to have it as `object_id`, and then call `SomeObject.query.get(object_id)` a second time?

I didn't see anything about this in the documentation (though I suppose I could have missed something), and all the other questions here that I could find were for other languages and had mixed answers.

Comment: Hard so say without knowing what "do stuff" and "do more stuff" means. At the end of the day, actually evaluating the performance of your code (e.g. with the `timeit` [module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html)) is likely more insightful than asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, when you're using the ORM, you'd do the second, but as a method:

```
class Foo(Model):
    def bar(self, param):
        ... work on self ...
```

If you pass in the `object_id`, that can be useful for bulk operation, but consider if passing in queryset instead is more appropriate for your use case:

```
def bar1(object_id, param):
    queryset = session.query(Foo).where(id=object_id)
    bar2(queryset, param)

def bar2(queryset, param): 
    queryset.update(...)
```

That way, you can use the same method (`bar2`) when updating both single row or when the queryset has more complex WHERE clause.